# What is this type of function called ( obj => { console.log(obj.var) } )

Tags: javascript

( obj => { console.log(obj.var)  } )

im specifically asking about the => part. as Webstorm does not like them.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I am pretty sure it is used to represent a function.

Comment: => is a fat arrow

Comment: This is ES6 Arrow functions

Comment: thanks! that was it "arrow function"

Comment: Its called arrow function, its the new addition of ecma script

Comment: See this http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies